# Target all link by parent class, add "rel" attribute to link (without jQuery)

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

[I have this Codepen demonstrating how to do it with jQuery](https://codepen.io/seezee/pen/gOmjxpp). I tried to do it with vanilla Javascript but couldn't get it to work. How would you go about this in plain ES6?

HTML:

```
<div class="external">
  <figure>
    <a href="https://via.placeholder.com/150" target="_blank">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" class="vc_single_image-wrapper" width="150" height="150">
    </a>
    </figure>
</div>
<div class="external">
  <figure>
    <a href="https://via.placeholder.com/150" target="_blank">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" class="vc_single_image-wrapper" width="150" height="150">
    </a>
    </figure>
</div>
<p>Placeholder images courtesty of <a href="https://placeholder.com" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">Placeholder.com</a></p>
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  // Scan the webpage for all class names of 'external'.
  $(".external").each(function () {
    // For each class name of 'external' found, find descendant tag "a" of that div and apply the rel attribute.
    $(".external a").attr("rel", "external noopener");
  });
});
```

Comment: You should add the code you attempted to your question. There may have been something simple you missed.

Comment: Unfortunately, I didn't keep a copy of it — I would have preferred to do that. Would have been far more informative to know where I went wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just do `document.querySelectorAll('.external a').forEach` to iterate over all of them:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.external a').forEach((el) => {
    el.setAttribute('rel', 'external noopener');
});
```

```html
<div class="external">
  <figure>
    <a href="https://via.placeholder.com/150" target="_blank">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" class="vc_single_image-wrapper" width="150" height="150">
    </a>
    </figure>
</div>
<div class="external">
  <figure>
    <a href="https://via.placeholder.com/150" target="_blank">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" class="vc_single_image-wrapper" width="150" height="150">
    </a>
    </figure>
</div>
<p>Placeholder images courtesty of <a href="https://placeholder.com" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">Placeholder.com</a></p>
```